# How to show new / updated data using datatables.js

Tags: datatables

**What I have**

A sort of master detail setup.
The master datatable has a checkbox column clicking on which trigger's an AJAX call.

```js
function makeAjaxCall(inProductId) {

    var url = "/Products/GetUpdatesForProduct/"

    var request = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        data: { productId: inProductId},
        dataType: "JSON"
    });

    request.done(function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
            console.log(result);
            bindProductUpdates(result);
        }
        else {
            alert("No updates found!");
        }

    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        alert("Request failed.");
    });
}
```

The function that does the binding to the detail table:

```js
function bindProductUpdates(productUpdates) {

    var oSettings = $('#productUpdatesTable').dataTable().fnSettings();
    oSettings._iDisplayLength = 5;
    $('#productUpdatesTable').dataTable().fnDraw();

    $('#productUpdatesTable').DataTable({

        "data": productUpdates.UpdatesForProduct,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "aoColumns": [
                        {
                            "sName": "",
                            "sClass": "checkbox-column",
                            "bSortable": false,
                            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                                return ' <input type="checkbox" value=' + full[1] + ' onclick="javascript:fnProductUpdatesCheckboxClickHandler(this,' + full[1] + ')"; />';

                            }

                        },
                         {
                             "sName": "Updated Date/Time",
                             "bSortable": true,
                             "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                                 return '<span title=\"' + full[2] + '\">' + full[2] + '</span>';

                             }
                         }

        ]
    });
}
```

**What's not happening**

So what I am trying to do is to use the same table to show new data based on the result of the AJAX call. The data structure remains same.

It works for the first click but on subsequent clicks 
Datatable complains:

```
Cannot reinitialise DataTable
```

What do I do to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [**`destroy`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) option :

```js
$('#productUpdatesTable').DataTable({
    destroy: true, //<--
    "data": productUpdates.UpdatesForProduct,
    ...
})
```

> Destroy any existing table matching the selector and replace with the
>   new options.

However, you could make the dataTable AJAX based itself, instead of populating `data` with the result of an AJAX call :

```js
var table = $('#productUpdatesTable').DataTable({
   ajax : {
     url: "/Products/GetUpdatesForProduct/",
     cache: false,
     data: { productId: inProductId},
     dataSrc: "productUpdates.UpdatesForProduct"  
    },
    "bProcessing": true,
   ...
})
```

By that, you just need to call `table.ajax.reload()` when `inProductId` changes.